# Find the number in an array which is closest to an given number

Tags: algorithm, assembly

Exercise from an Assembly course I'm enrolled in:

> ### Find closest number.
>
> Add the following into the data section:
>
> nums  dd  23h,75h,111h,0abch,443h,1000h,5h,2213h,433a34h,0deadbeafh
>
> This is an array of numbers.
>
> Write a program that receives a number x as input, and finds the dword
>   inside the array nums, which is the closest to x. (We define the
>   distance between two numbers to be the absolute value of the
>   difference: |a-b|).
>
> Example:
>
> For the input of 100h, the result will be 111h, because 111h is closer
>   to 100h than any other number in the nums array. (|100h - 111h| =
>   11h).

Full exercise-sheet on [GitHub - xorpd](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/4_basic_assembly/3_memory/5_ex/2_write_code/write_code.txt)

Here's my approach. Please pay attention to the comments which I've added to explain my ideas.

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc' 

section '.data' data readable writeable
    nums  dd  23h, 75h, 111h, 0abch, 443h, 1000h, 5h, 2213h, 433a34h, 0deadbeafh
    nums_end:

section '.text' code readable executable

start:
    xor         esi,        esi                     ; Current array-index.
    mov         ecx,        (nums_end - nums) / 4   ; Array-length
    mov         ebx,        0x100                   ; Input, Value to compare too. 
    mov         edx,        0x7fffffff              ; Smallest value found until now. Start with the greatest value possible.
    mov         edi,        edi                     ; Index of the element with the smallest value.
    ; -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
check_next:
    mov         eax,        ebx                     ; Make a copy compare-value.
    mov         ebp,        dword[nums + 4 * esi]   ; Move the value of the current element to ebp.
    cmp         eax,        ebp                     ; If eax is smaller then ebp then we must not subtract ebp from eax.
    jb          eax_is_smaller                      ;   This would result in a negative number. ...
    sub         eax,        ebp
    jmp         subtraction_done
eax_is_smaller:
    sub         ebp,        eax                     ; ... subtract eax from ebp instead.
    mov         eax,        ebp                     ; ... and move the result to eax.
subtraction_done:
    cmp         eax,        edx                     ; Compare the result to the current smallest value.
    jnb         prepare_next
    mov         edx,        eax                     ; If the result is smaller then the current smallest value the result becomes the smallest value.
    mov         edi,        esi                     ; Save the index of the smallest value.
prepare_next:
    inc         esi                                 ; Increment the array-index.
    loop        check_next                          ; Check the next array-element.
    ; -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov         eax,        dword[nums + 4 * edi]   ; Use the index of the nearest element to get the value. Then print it to stdout.
    call        print_eax                           ; Print to stdout. Function provided by the tutor.
    ; Exit the process:
    push        0
    call        [ExitProcess]


include 'training.inc'
```

I've tried it with different compare-values and it provided the expected value every time. So I guess it's generally correct. Nevertheless I'm not completely satisfied. I have used a lot of register.

How can I reduce the number of register? I have found a solution for the problem with getting negative values when subtracting a larger number from a smaller number. It works but it isn't elegant. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov edi, edi    ; Index of the element with the smallest value.
> ```

An error here. You want to zero this register. Use `xor`

---

A better strategy will be to simply subtract without looking at which number is the largest and then later take the absolute value of the difference.

```
    mov     eax, [nums + 4 * esi]
    sub     eax, ebx
    jnl     IsPositive
    neg     eax
IsPositive:
    cmp     eax, edx ; Compare the result to the current smallest value.
    jnb     prepare_next
    mov     edx, eax
    mov     edi, esi
prepare_next:
```

Less code and less register usage!

---

A further optimization will come from not using `ECX` as a loop counter. You can determine if the loop is completed by looking at the `ESI` array index.

```
    xor     esi, esi         ;Start at index 0
check_next:
    ...
    inc     esi
    cmp     esi, (nums_end - nums) / 4
    jb      check_next
```

---

In stead of branching, you could use one of the conditional forms of `mov`.
Same code size but faster. Having less labels is also nicer.

```
    cmp     eax, edx ; Compare the result to the current smallest value.
    cmovb   edx, eax
    cmovb   edi, esi
```

About coding style.

> ```
> mov eax, dword[nums + 4 * edi]
> ```

Does your assembler requires you to write this redundant mention of the size?
Do you get an error if you write it shorter?

```
    mov     eax, [nums + 4 * edi]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Goanna try out the access in brackets-syntax this evening.